# Why this case pandas dataframe assign raise TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Environment:

```
Python 3.6.4
pandas 0.23.4
```

My code is below.

```
from math import sqrt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6]})

df = df.assign(d = lambda z: sqrt(z.x**2 + z.y**2))
```

The bottom line raise TypeError like below.

```
...
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Without sqrt, it works.

```
df = df.assign(d2 = lambda z: z.x**2 + z.y**2)
df
Out[6]:
   x  y  d2
0  1  4  17
1  2  5  29
2  3  6  45
```

And apply also works.

```
df['d3'] = df.apply(lambda z: sqrt(z.x**2 + z.y**2), axis=1)
df
Out[8]:
   x  y  d2        d3
0  1  4  17  4.123106
1  2  5  29  5.385165
2  3  6  45  6.708204
```

What's the matter with the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.sqrt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html) - it works also with 1d arrays, while `sqrt` from `math` works only with scalars:

```
df = df.assign(d = lambda z: np.sqrt(z.x**2 + z.y**2))
```

Another solution is use `**(1/2)`:

```
df = df.assign(d = lambda z: (z.x**2 + z.y**2)**(1/2))
```

---

```
print (df)
   x  y         d
0  1  4  4.123106
1  2  5  5.385165
2  3  6  6.708204
```

Your solution working, because `axis=1` in `apply` working by scalars, but like @jpp mentioned, `apply` should not be preferred as it involves a Python-level row-wise loop.

```
df.apply(lambda z: print(z.x), axis=1)
1
2
3
```

Comment: thanks a lot. pandas.apply is executed with each value(scalar), so apply works.  In this case, I should not use apply.

Comment: @rootpetit - exactly, apply here is not necessary, because exist vectorized solution(s).

Answer (score 0):

pandas series object is like a numpy array, you cannot operate a math module
that is searching for a single object, and not a series.
the default math operations are valid , but not functions that do not work on arrays/ series.

what you can do is:

```
df = df.assign(d = lambda z: (z.x**0.5 + z.y**0.5))
```

or

```
df['d'] = df.z.x**0.5 + df.y.x**0.5
```

which is defined in pandas standard operations.

Comment: thank you for your answer and @jezwels answer I understand why it works, and not.